# Density type puzzle

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

Inspired by [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90049/the-first-density-puzzle) I decided to make something similar. To warm up, I made something simple. It follows the rules set up by @Dmihawk except for the size:

[image]

**Final answer: (1,6)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The colors can be decoded

> using their RGB values: each one is either 0, 125, or 250. Decoding each color as ternary yields **SIMPLE**.
>  (Not sure what the other letter could be, because this uses all of the given information...)

Comment: (maybe you need to also consider the colour of the outside?)

Comment: @boboquack (That's pure black, which wouldn't correspond to a letter.)

Comment: (oh ok, I wrongly assumed a 000-based system)

Comment: "B ..." meaning "be ..." ?

Comment: or maybe 2... meaning "too"?  Which it isn't ;)

Comment: I seem to have misunderstood the "Final answer" notation from the linked puzzle. I thought the two numbers were the number of words followed by the number of letters.