# Density type puzzle 2

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher, visual

Here's another puzzle of [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90049/the-first-density-puzzle) type. Perhaps my next one will be complex enough to require the full $72$ x $72$ size.

[image]

**Final answer: (5,2,5)**

Comment: Is visual the only applicable tag here? The original post said that the tags should indicate the techniques involved to find the solution

Comment: @PiIsNot3 I'll add "Cipher" though it really isn't. It's a communication protocol (big hint!).

Comment: Possibly that hint was too big.

Comment: @Jasen It probably was. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The symbols look like

> morse code  - .. ... .- .-. . -.. .... . .-. .-. .. -. --.

but decoded it spells

TIS A RED HERRING

but it's a clue to the steganography:

> If  blue is long and yellow is short and a notch is a pause

It says

> -- --- .-. ... . .. -. -.-. --- .-.. --- .-.

which translates to

> MORSE IN COLOR

Comment: Ugh, I got the red herring message but didn’t know what to do with the notches. Good job!

Comment: I edited your answer to hide essential information under spoiler blocks, just a heads up

Comment: edit clash, sorry.

Comment: Sorry, shouldn’t have been so quick to edit, hope everything’s ok now :)