# Density type puzzle 3

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, english

Another puzzle in the spirit of [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90049/the-first-density-puzzle)  puzzle. Enjoy!

[image]

**Final answer: (8,7,4)**

**Hint**

> Tag "English" added

**Hint 2**

> Colors have names

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is:

> **NINETEEN COLORED DICE**

How we get this:

> Take the color of every colored dice (white, orange, red, black, green), and index into it by the number on the dice. If the number is invalid (indexing 6 into white, for example), then the result is undefined (using _ as a placeholder). The result we get is:
>
> ```
>  w_ignore
>  nineteen
>  colo_red
>  _dwiwc_e
> ```
>
> Taking the top line as a command (ignore 'w's), and removing it from the output, this changes into the following:
>
> ```
>  nineteen
>  colo_red
>  _d i c_e
> ```
>
> So, the answer is "nineteen colored dice". This makes sense because (looking at the image) there are 19 colored dice, and 13 white dice.