# Density type puzzle 4

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, english

In the spirit of [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90049/the-first-density-puzzle) puzzle, here's another (with dice!). Enjoy!

[image]

**Final answer: (8)**

**Hint**

> The first column is a distraction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Density Puzzle™ clues the word

> **INTEGERS**

The mechanism:

> From Hint 1, we ignore the first column of dice. Then, take the English word version of the numbers shown in the dice in the third column and index into it by the value of the corresponding dice in the second column. This gives us:
>
>  F**I**VE
>  O**N**E
>  **T**WO
>  THR**E**E
>  EI**G**HT
>  SEV**E**N
>  FOU**R**
>  **S**IX

Comment: You got it! Well done. :-)