# Density type puzzle 6

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

Another puzzle in the spirit of [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90049/the-first-density-puzzle) puzzle. No RGB tricks or distractions. Enjoy!

[image]

**Final answer: (7, 6, 11)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The border is:

> A morse code, blues mean bars and yellows mean dots.
>  The message will be "ONE SQUARE OF 6X6 TWO VERTICAL LINES".

Based on it:

> We need to tile the $9$ tetrominoes into squares with two vertical lines.
>  The configuration will be this.
>
>  [image]

Now:

> If we treat black cells as 1's and white cells as 0's, we can read the message in binary.
>  The message is this.
>
>  [image]

Maybe there's a slight error here, but you can read the final answer as:

> **MORSING BINARZ[Y] TETROMINOES**

Comment: So fast! You are of course completely correct. And yes, I made a mistake with the "Y", rendering it as "Z". Sorry about that. Very well done!