# Density type puzzle 7

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

Another puzzle in the spirit of [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90049/the-first-density-puzzle) puzzle. It was simple to make, but perhaps less simple to solve. We shall see. Enjoy!

[image]

**Final answer: (7)**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This image has been modified by:

> ...moving the first row 0 pixels right, the second row 6 pixels right, the third row 12 pixels right, and so on. Any pixels that move off the right edge wrap around to the left side. (The pixels are in "groups" of five horizontally: this means each row is moved by one more group than the last.)

Undoing this transformation gives the following image:

> [image]