# The Digit Gambit

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

A puzzle in the spirit of the Density™ [puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90049/the-first-density-puzzle). Enjoy!

[image]

**Final answer: (3, 6)**

Hint

> The white figures are used in a known game. The game has a sort of board.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR**: The answer to this puzzle is:

> **TOE TACTIC**

---

**Explanation:** Note first of all that the puzzle itself bears a resemblance to:

> A game of **TIC-TAC-TOE**, also known as *Noughts and Crosses*. This game is usually played between two players using pen and paper, on a board shaped like a hash or octothorpe: #.

Note next that:

> You can treat each of the eight outer spaces on the board as if it is a different shape, made of either two or three lines:
>
>  [image]

Looking familiar? Of course! Because:

> These are the symbols shown in the centre of the puzzle.

So if we next:

> Consider the white parts of the puzzle as being noughts and crosses set out on a tic-tac-toe grid, we can replace each of the black symbols with its corresponding X or O from the #-shaped grid, to get:
>
> ```
>  O / OOO / X
>  O / XO  / OXOX
>  O / XX  / OXOX
> ```

What can we do with this now? Well, how about trying to interpret this using:

> Morse code, since we have only a message made of only two different characters.

By doing so, we find that:

> Letting 'O' (nought) be dash and 'X' be dot, we get:
>
> ```
>  - / --- / .
>  - / .-  / -.-.
>  - / ..  / -.-.
> ```

Which (as stated at the very top) translates to:

> **TOE**
>  **TAC**
>  **TIC**
>
>  or when written in the (3,6) format of the expected answer: **TOE TACTIC**.

Notice finally that the title is:

> Synonymous with this answer... Toe = Digit, and Tactic = Gambit. Everything ties up nicely!

Comment: Well done! A small addendum to your excellent explanation is that the title is actually the answer in disguise. Hope you enjoyed it!

Comment: @Jens Oh yes, forgot to mention that! Will edit in for completeness...