# The sign unseen

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

Another puzzle in the spirit of the Density™ [puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90049/the-first-density-puzzle). Enjoy!

[image]

**Final answer: (7)**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is:

> **BRAILLE**

How to solve? Notice first that there are:

> 6 different-shaped symbols in the image, each of which can represent a section in a diagram of 2×3 sections that looks like a domino:
>
>  [image]

If we then:

> Group (and order) the symbols by rainbow colour, positioning each symbol as per the domino-style diagram above (i.e. _ | = top left corner, | _ = top right, etc.) we can see that they form [symbols in English Braille](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_Braille). Translating them into letters, we get the letters of the word **BRAILLE** itself - the answer to this puzzle:
>
>  [image]

At this point, now that we know the encoding, we can see that there was another clue in the puzzle that I inadvertently skipped past altogether!  Notice that:

> If we split the initial puzzle into 6 equal-sized blocks and replace each symbol (regardless of its shape and colour) with a dot, we have 6 more Braille letter dominos! Translating these as above we see the clue '**RAINBW**', suggesting that if we'd got to the Braille conclusion just from its initial appearance we should now focus on the symbols within their rainbow colours, and derive the solution as laid out in the spoiler block above... (However, since I'd solved the previous tic-tac-toe themed puzzle in this series, I was already subliminally programmed to associate these symbols with a grid of some sort, and initially missed this subtle step!)
>
>  [image]

This solution also explains the title, since:

> Braille is a letter system *for the blind*, made of raised dots that are read by *touch* (hence, 'unseen').

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on the grouping transformation? rot13("pbeerfcbaqvat frpgvbaf") is a little vaguer than I can follow.

Comment: rot13(lbh zvffrq gur fbyhgvba jura lbh gnxr oenvyyr ba chmmyr nf vg vf. Vs chmmyr vf bayl guvf naq gung - V rkcrpgrq fbzrguvat zber)

Comment: @JanIvan Oh, I totally didn't see that! Will add :)

Comment: @Avi Diagrams added - should be clearer now, I hope!

Comment: @JanIvan Edited accordingly, with diagrams to explain more clearly :)

Comment: Much better - my upvote is already with you

Comment: An excellent answer again! And without a single additional hint. Gotta make the next one tougher. Well done!