# Emblem gestures

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

Another puzzle in the spirit of the Density™ [puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90049/the-first-density-puzzle). Just monochrome this time I'm afraid. Enjoy!

[image]

**Final answer: (3, 4, 5)**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer:

> Fun With Flags

Building on the same reasoning as per @Belhenix:

> Semaphore alphabet spells "Sheldon Cooper Presents", and as a TBBT watcher this is immediately recognizable as the introduction to his ridiculous video series, "Fun With Flags" - which also fits with the semaphore flags used.

Answer (score 9):

I believe the answer should be

> DNA FROM NIMOY

Reasoning:

> The image has [flag semaphore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_semaphore) represetation, spelling "Sheldon Cooper Presents". I'm not a Big Bang Theory fan but some quick googling led me to the [Christmas episode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bath_Item_Gift_Hypothesis), where Sheldon receives a napkin autographed and used by Leonard Nimoy and he claims he has his DNA now.

Comment: Wow! That was unbelievably fast! You solved the clue correctly, but your answer is not the intended one. The intended answer aligns more closely with the clue.

Comment: As wrong answers go this is fantastic.