# A big playhouse

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, jigsaw-puzzle

A puzzle in the spirit of the Density™ [puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90049/the-first-density-puzzle). This one probably requires a bit of googling. Enjoy!

[image]

**Final answer: (8)**

Hint:

> The tabs of the puzzle pieces are at most 2 units long.

Hint 2:

> Ternary

Hint 3:

> Just 4 u: Sometimes a number is just a number

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved at last! I believe that the final answer is:

> **KRONBORG** or **ELSINORE**

The completed jigsaw looks like this:

> [image]
>  (with different shades of red, dark grey and light grey to show distinctions between adjacent pieces)
>
>  Clearly we have here the words 'HOME LANGUAGE' on the background of the flag of Denmark. We will need to derive from the rest of this picture a word or phrase which has some relevance in the Danish tongue...

How can we find these words?

> Let's first highlight the tabs between each piece (shown here in blue):
>
>  [image]

With the hints in mind we now see that in the three central 'pixels' of each tile edge that jigsaws into another tile we have:

> Numbers written in ternary. Thanks to a prompt from the OP in comments we know we must read them by orientating each side towards the top before inferring a number from it. In this way we read the following:
>
>  Right-hand edges of top row:
>  010 / 001 / 201 = 3 / 1 / 19 in base-10 = **C / A / S** in A1Z26
>
>  Bottom edges of top row:
>  202 / 110 / 012 = 20 / 12 / 5 in base-10 = **T / L / E** in A1Z26
>
>  Right-hand edges of centre row:
>  002 / 002 / 120 = 2 / 2 / 15 in base-10 = **B / B / O** in A1Z26
>
>  Bottom edges of centre row:
>  200 / 122 / 120 / 202 = 18 / 14 / 15 / 20 in base-10 = **R / N / O / T** in A1Z26
>
>  Right-hand edges of bottom row:
>  002 / 002 = 2 / 2 in base-10 = **B / B** in A1Z26
>
>  Taken altogether, this reads: **CASTLEBBORNOTBB**.

So what does this mean? Well, realise that:

> This is the phrase 'CASTLE BB OR NOT BB', or reading 'BB' as '2B' - or rather, 'to be' - it could be read as '**Castle, "To be, or not to be"**'. Since "To be, or not to be" is a famous quote from the Shakespeare play *Hamlet*, what we are ultimately being asked for here is *the name of the castle in the play*, which after all is set in Denmark.
>
>  In the play itself, the castle is known as **Elsinore**. However, in Danish (Hamlet's *home language*) it is more widely known as **Kronborg**.

This satisfies the title since:

> A castle from a Shakespeare play could certainly be considered a 'big *play*house'!

Comment: You are very close!  To "read" a set of tabs rot13(whfg ebgngr gur chmmyr cvrpr hagvy gur frg bs gnof ner ba gbc).

Comment: @Jens Think I got there at last! Took me long enough - thanks for the nudge!

Comment: Absolutely perfect! And yes, Kronborg was what I was looking for. Superbly done! :)

Answer (score 1):

The tiles fit together as:

> HOME
>  LANG
>  UAGE

With the stripes meaning:

> the Flag of Denmark

Where:

> The root language (of Scandinavia) is OLD NORSE (8)
>  but the answer should be one word, and I neglected the title...

The title refers to:

> The Danish Royal Theater (skuespilhuset)

The tabs:

> could be 2 digit binary numbers; perhaps coordinates
>  such as hh:mm:ss South, hh:mm:ss East

but I am lazy and lost...

Comment: I agree with the first two steps, but how does the answer relate to the title?

Comment: The first two steps are fine, but there are more clues in the puzzle. And the "Final answer (8)" means the answer is a single word with 8 letters.