# Density-type puzzle: Is This Too Difficult?

Tags: cipher, visual

After seeing some of the puzzles that other people have made, I decided to try making one of my own. I especially like the idea of [Density](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90049/the-first-density-puzzle) puzzles, invented by @Dmihawk. This is the first puzzle I've ever put on here, so I'm not sure how easy or hard it will be. Here it is:
[image]

**Solution: (4,2,4)**

If you like the puzzle, or if it stumps you, please give it an upvote!

Even though the answer has been found, feel free to post the answer if you find it yourself. I will give it an upvote, but I'll only accept the first correct answer.

**Hint 1:**

> The white parts are *just a little bit more* than binary.

**Hint 2:**

> You wont be able to understand the message in the white parts without the black parts.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Puzzling! Hints can be hidden in spoiler blocks by beginning a line with the two symbols '>!' followed by a space, and then your text. Hold off on hints for a day or two though - let us check out your puzzle as is first! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think it's too difficult!

The black bars:

> The long and short black bars are Morse code. They spell ROT7. That will definitely be useful!

The white pixels:

> The white pixels are ternary: I read the white pixels in the first black bar as 111, the next as 001, and the next as 002. This is probably an alphabetic sort of thing, and we see a 222 in the fifth and eighth bars, so I'll treat that as Z and treat 001 as A.

So I decode the white pixels as:

> MABLZBLZXTLR

Applying the clue from the black bars:

> THISGISGEASY

Which is kind of weird, but regardless I can see the answer:

> THIS IS EASY

But did I reach it in the intended manner?

> Was I supposed to treat ternary 000 as A, and ternary 222 as a space? Did I ROT7 correctly? Hmm.

Comment: You found the right answer, but you did do a couple of things wrong. You did the ROT in the wrong direction, and your Number to Letter assumption was incorrect. However, your second guess on that was right. Coincidentally, only by making both of those mistakes together are you able to still find the answer. So good on ya.

Comment: If you liked this one, I made another Density puzzle you might enjoy: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/92091/density-type-puzzle

Comment: By the way, the title was a rhetorical question. It was supposed to be a reference to the answer. I decided to do that because I saw other people doing it, and I thought it was a fun idea.