# Density-type puzzle: __________

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

I made another [Density](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90049/the-first-density-puzzle) puzzle. This one is a bit simpler than my last one in that it has less steps, but at the same it feels a bit harder (though I can't judge that accurately as the creator). Here it is:
[image]

**Solution: (8,8)**

**Hint 1:**

> The background colors are not arbitrary, as @Jens so brilliantly realized. In fact, they are **very** specific.

**Hint 2:**

> To solve the dots, remember that Morse code has very specific rules for its use.

Comment: Rot13(Oernxvat qbja rnpu bs gur guerr pbybef vagb gurve ETO pbzcbaragf tvirf ahzoref juvpu bayl unir qvtvgf orgjrra mreb naq gjb.) Is that significant?

Comment: That is exactly right. Good job!

Comment: I have to ask because of "steganography" tag - is there a message in "dots", and only "dots" are enough to create half of solution?

Comment: The steganography tag is there because the answer is "hidden" in the image. To answer your question, however, yes, the dots are just a part of the solution.

Comment: Really can't tell if the dots are unevenly positioned or if it's one of those brilliant optical illusions.

Comment: They are uneven, but that was just laziness on my part; it's not a clue in any way, shape, or form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution is:

> Untitled document

First part:

> Morse in dots, where one black dot means "dot", and three is "dash". Three white dots are separator - UNTITLED

Second part:

> What [Jens](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/57247/jens) found was close. Colours in this order as RGB are:
>  222,10,112
>  2,202,110
>  11,111,201
>  Which is in base-3 letters: ZCNBTLDMS
>  With shift by one (or caesar cipher +1) it is: A DOCUMENT

Comment: You got it! However, you didn't need to do the shift. It may be different from how other people do it, but when I make puzzles, 000 = A and 222 = _.