# LongEst in anothEr way?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, anagram

A puzzle in the spirit of the Density™ [puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90049/the-first-density-puzzle). Too simple? Anyway, enjoy!

[image]

**Final answer: (15)**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the answer is

> DEFENCELESSNESS

and obtained as follows.

> First, look at each individual colour's presence or absence in each of the 5x5 rows to give a 5x5-pixel bitmap. We get, with various orientations:
>  red C
>  orange D (or maybe O)
>  yellow E, M, W, 3
>  green F
>  blue L
>  black Z, N
>  purple S, 5
>  Now, the bottom row seems to indicate *how many* of each kind of letter we take; indeed there are 15 coloured pixels there. And I think the only word that uses the given balance of letters is DEFENCELESSNESS. It happens to use the *same* letter (E) for all the yellow pixels and the *same* letter (N) for all the black ones.

In comments, jafe very plausibly suggests that perhaps

> this word is the longest English word that uses only a single vowel

which seems plausible enough

> though often this sort of thing depends on what you're willing to count as a word; e.g., perhaps "defencelessnesses" is even better

and would explain the title.

Comment: That was quick! Can you also relate the word to the title?

Comment: Just a guess, maybe it's the rot13(ybatrfg jbeq jvgu n fvatyr havdhr ibjry)?

Comment: Seems pretty plausible.

Comment: Not sure it is the longest English word rot13(hfvat n fvatyr ibjry), but it seems to be the longest using rot13(whfg gur ibjry r). Hence the capitals in the title. I'm not convinced it can be pluralized, but maybe I'm wrong. Anyway, good job!