# Rosetta's Stone

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, anagram

Another puzzle in the spirit of the Density™ [puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90049/the-first-density-puzzle). Fairly hard I suspect. Enjoy!

[image]

**Final Answer: (6, 7)**

Version for the color impaired [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WP3Hh.jpg).

Hint 1

> All letters in the first word are unique.

Hint 2

> Glyphs can be placed on top of each other. Some glyph parts are then covered more times than other parts.
>  <sub>*It can be difficult to give hints when I don't know where people are stuck. Partial results encouraged.*</sub>

Hint 3

> There are 7 colors of the rainbow, starting with red. This info, plus a telegraph coding method in the diagram, should give you two letters of the second word, right off the bat.

Hint 4

> Each of the figures on the left contain the first word. Each of the figures on the right contain the second word. Hence the title.

Comment: I think you may be overestimating how easy (/ possible) the [rot13](http://rot13.com)(qrpbzcbfvgvba) is here...

Comment: @Deusovi I know it's not easy, but it is possible. I've done it myself. The second word is easier than the first, though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Important preliminary note**

The cleverest ideas in what follows are not mine but Deusovi's, posted by him in comments to the first version of this answer. Some of the others are Stiv's, also posted in comments.

If you like this answer, please go find something of theirs and upvote it.

**Solution**

The words we are looking for are

> DOUBLE ENCODED. (That is: the words are DOUBLE and ENCODED, and they have also been encoded twice each.)

On each side of the image are

> *two* representations of the same set of letters, overlaid and represented as follows: for each pixel, count the number of letters whose representation covers that pixel, getting a number from 1 to 7 (the number of letters in the RH word); convert that to a colour in "rainbow order": red=1, orange=2, yellow=3, green=4, blue=5, indigo=6, violet=7. (Background grey for 0.) So, e.g., a pixel used in exactly two of the letters will be coloured orange.

The left side

> says DOUBLE. At the top we have the letters themselves on a 5x5 grid. (So e.g. the top-right pixel is yellow, meaning that 3 of the letters include that pixel: the O, U, and E.) At the bottom we have Braille. Here's a picture of all the letters so you can check that the numbers add up:
>
> ```
> # # # # .    # # # # #    # . . . #    # # # # .    # . . . .    # # # # #    6 4 4 4 3
> # . . . #    # . . . #    # . . . #    # . . . #    # . . . .    # . . . .    6 . . . 4
> # . . . #    # . . . #    # . . . #    # # # # .    # . . . .    # # # # #    6 2 2 2 4
> # . . . #    # . . . #    # . . . #    # . . . #    # . . . .    # . . . .    6 . . . 4
> # # # # .    # # # # #    # # # # #    # # # # .    # # # # #    # # # # #    6 6 6 6 4
> ```
>
> and the Braille:
>
> ```
> oo  o.  o.  o.  o.  o.  61
> .o  .o  ..  o.  o.  .o  23
> ..  o.  oo  ..  o.  ..  31
> D   O   U   B   L   E
> ```

The right side

> says ENCODED. At the top we have flag semaphore. At the bottom we have Morse code, with the following convention: each element (dot or dash) is represented by two pixels. A dot uses only the left-hand pixel. A dash uses both. (A real Morse code dash is 3x the length of a dot, but that would have made things too obvious.) Elements are written from the left, so to speak. Here's the semaphore:
>
> ```
> . . /   . . .   \ . .   \ . .   . | .   . . /   . | .   2 2 2
> . o .   . o .   . o .   - o .   . o .   . o .   . o .   1 o .
> . | .   / . \   . | .   . . .   . | .   . | .   . | .   1 5 1
>   E       N       C       O       D       E       D
> ```
>
> and the Morse:
>
> ```
> E .    1.
> N -.   11 1.
> C -.-. 11 1. 11 1.
> O ---  11 11 11
> D -..  11 1. 1.
> E .    1.
> D -..  11 1. 1.
> totals 75 51 42 1
> ```

**Credit where due**

> Deusovi suggested the colours-indicating-counts thing and the idea that the blocks below the "main" images are themselves other overlaid representations rather than merely indicating what letters to use in what order. Stiv suggested the Morse interpretation of the lower right (and also suggested a very plausible second word, which unfortunately happened to be wrong). I did some ineffectual scutwork trying out other interpretations of the image, all wrong; found the first word after Deusovi suggested how it all works; and found the second word, admittedly by telling a computer what to look for. Again: go and upvote some of their stuff!

Comment: +1 for a lot of effort :)

Comment: Heh. There should be no marks for _effort_.

Comment: I hope it'll give Jens some indication of the sort of thing that might be necessary in order to turn this into a solvable puzzle. (Or to nudge solvers in the right direction to solve it, if in some sense it's solvable already.)

Comment: I suspect that letters are overlaid, and the color of each counts how many letter components are on each space: red means "used by one letter", orange "used by two letters", and so on. (Top left is the letters drawn out, top right is flag semaphore, bottom left is Braille, bottom right is... ASCII?) But if that's the case, the decomposition seems basically impossible.

Comment: [...] Even if it *does* happen to be unambiguous, it would seem to require heavy trial-and-error, or coding, to actually do.

Comment: @Deusovi Some clever ideas there.

Comment: If you're right then I think it's more do-able than you think. I already have a conjecture for the first word which I'm just checking.

Comment: Looks right. I have to be AFK for a bit now, though.

Comment: My money's on rot13(Frpbaq bar orvat GEBHOYR, hfvat fvzvyne zrgubq nf sbe gur Oenvyyr ohg sbe Zbefr Pbqr, jvgu YU cvkry bs rnpu qnfu orvat gur qbg naq obgu qnfu cvkryf orvat n qnfu. Abgr gur YU cvkry vf nyjnlf 'n uvture ahzore' pbybhe guna gur EU bar, yraqvat jrvtug gb guvf...)

Comment: Looks extremely plausible.

Comment: (It turns out not to be that particular word, but your interpretation of the lower right is correct.)

Comment: Ah, well done for pulling it altogether - happy to be of service :) @Jens will be very happy!

Comment: I hope so! But I feel guilty getting a pile of MIPs that Deusovi really deserves most of.

Comment: Can you please explain how you're getting rot13(erq=1, benatr=2, lryybj=3 naq fb ba? Jung ner lbh bireynlvat? V'ir unq zhygvcyr nggrzcgf ng svthevat bhg jung lbh zrna, ohg V pna'g svther vg bhg)

Comment: I've edited my answer to clarify this. It may still be insufficiently clear, in which case let me know. (But I'll be AFK for the next several hours.)

Comment: YES!! So glad it was finally, not just attempted, but solved! And what a power collaboration! Very nice to see. Just a note and a small request: (1) When the encoding method is understood, the solution is entirely possible to do by hand, for both words. (2) I see you've written out how the top left figure becomes a word when "decompressed". Could you perhaps do the same for the other three? Just so it's clear for everybody. Thank you and again, super well done! :)

Comment: I thought it was useful for the top left one because that's the only one where there's any _ambiguity_. (There's only one way to rot13(jevgr QBHOYR va Oenvyyr) or to rot13(jevgr RAPBQRQ va Zbefr pbqr).) I can do the others too if you think it's valuable but not right now this minute.

Comment: OK, all those are done now.

Comment: (I'm sure it's possible to do the RH one by hand, but it was something like five lines of Python code so I did it the easy way.)