# Where art thou?

Tags: riddle, poetry

An appealing interlude...

> Recent in youth, I earned some praise
>   On time has passed, those were the days
>   So now I'm idle
>   E're by myself
>   Seeking a saviour, on any shelf
>
> Some say I'm hard, but that isn't true
>   Though I require, some work from you
>   Oodles of hints
>   No hint was small
>   Even the title, s'plained for y'all

**What am I?**

Hint

> It's a puzzle about another puzzle.

Comment: I've got an idea but I'm hung up on how "shelf" serves the riddle. Any possibility of a hint there?

Comment: @anodyne You've found the one word I'm not completely happy with! Don't get hung up on it. Just see it as an idiom.

Comment: Are you a long unused puzzle tag?

Comment: @ Ébe Isaac No, but that's an interesting idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't claim to explain all the hints, but my guess is that you are

> [ROSETTA'S STONE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/93764/rosettas-stone), a previous puzzle of @Jens', as ROSES STONE on each first letter cannot be an accident

*Recent in youth, I earned some praise

On time has passed, those were the days

So now I'm idle

E're by myself

Seeking a saviour, on any shelf*

> That puzzle went unsolved and un-attempted for a few days despite double-digit upvotes. Mirroring that, the real-life Rosetta Stone garnered great interest centuries ago, before it was cracked.

*Some say I'm hard, but that isn't true

Though I require, some work from you

Oodles of hints

No hint was small

Even the title, s'plained for y'all*

> These lines tell us to go solve the other puzzle  - it's not that hard! Though "Where art thou?" suggests we have to go locate it first.

As for the hint,

> This would be a puzzle about the other puzzle as well as the "puzzling" Rosetta Stone.

As for the prelude "An appealing interlude...,"

> I have no idea. Perhaps this riddle was a bit of an intermission while we waited for someone to solve the other puzzle.

I'm surprised to see

> No reference to the language-learning software. Perhaps I am missing it.

Comment: You are so very close, I'm almost tempted to give you the checkmark! However, I was quite selfish when I wrote this riddle and the puzzle it refers to, is on this very site.

Comment: I think [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/93764/rosettas-stone) may be the droid... I mean, puzzle... you're looking for...

Comment: I've been baited into a puzzle way beyond my pay grade. Looking forward to reading solutions!

Comment: You don't need to solve the puzzle being referred to (though that would nice!) just identify it. And @Stiv is always worth listening to...

Comment: I feel silly but I confess I still don't get it. Perhaps someone else can help?

Comment: Stiv has a link to the answer in his comment. Just update your answer and the checkmark is yours.

Comment: Some notes: (1) The title and the "appeal" in "appealing interlude" refer to the need for a "saviour", i.e. someone to try to solve the puzzle referred to. And that puzzle is the one you correctly linked to. (2) There is no talk of language learning software as that isn't needed to solve that puzzle. Anyway, the checkmark is yours!