# A farm related sport?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, anagram

A puzzle in the spirit of the Density™ [puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90049/the-first-density-puzzle). I'll say that the overall philosophy used here is the same as in [Rosetta's Stone](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/93764/rosettas-stone). Also, the rainbow colors at the top are just for reference. Finally, the title holds a clue to one of the "languages" used. Enjoy!

[image]

**Final answer: (7, 7)**

Version for the color impaired [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1UsB.png).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this puzzle is:

> **CHICKEN FENCING**!

To solve this, notice that:

> 1. Similar to Jens' previous [Rosetta's Stone](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/93764/rosettas-stone) puzzle, the two 7-letter words are coded twice over, with two different mechanisms. This time around the mechanisms are (top) **[PIGPEN CIPHER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigpen_cipher)** and (bottom) **[MORSE CODE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code)**.
>  [image: Pigpen cipher and Morse code]
>  *<sup>(Source: Wikipedia)</sup>*
>
>  2. The rainbow ordering suggests we should translate colours into numbers using Red=1, Orange=2, Yellow=3, Green=4, Blue=5, Indigo=6 and Violet=7.

This then means that the coloured segments in:

> (i) the *top* diagrams show how many letters of each word incorporate that segment in their pigpen cipher representation;
>
>  (ii) the *bottom* diagrams show how many letters of each word incorporate that segment in their Morse code representations (so, for example, the first 3-pixel block for Word 1 indicates that all 7 letters require the first pixel to be shaded in their Morse symbol, and 4 of the letters require the second and third to be shaded also - this translates to 4 letters starting with a dash, and the other 3 starting with a dot).
>
>  [image: Count of segments and dots and dashes]
>
>  Explicitly:
>
>  For the first word, between its 7 letters we should see in pigpen:
>  - all 7 with a LEFT-hand edge in its symbols;
>  - 4 with a TOP edge;
>  - 4 with a RIGHT-hand edge;
>  - 5 with a BOTTOM edge;
>  - 2 with a DOT.
>
>  and in Morse:
>  - first symbol = 3 DOTS & 4 DASHES;
>  - second symbol = 6 DOTS;
>  - third symbol = 1 DOT & 3 DASHES;
>  - fourth symbol = 3 DOTS.
>
>  Meanwhile, for the second word, between its 7 letters we should see in pigpen:
>  - 6 with a LEFT-hand edge in its symbols;
>  - 6 with a TOP edge;
>  - 4 with a RIGHT-hand edge;
>  - 5 with a BOTTOM edge;
>  - 2 with a DOT.
>
>  and in Morse:
>  - first symbol = 3 DOTS & 4 DASHES;
>  - second symbol = 5 DOTS & 1 DASH;
>  - third symbol = 1 DOT & 2 DASHES;
>  - fourth symbol = 2 DOTS.

What then follows could well end up being a long drawn-out process of trial and error or guesswork. However, there were a few deductions that helped me to cut some corners along the way...

> A. Focusing on the first word, since all 7 letters had a left-hand edge in their (rectangular) pigpen symbols, the whole word had to be spelled using a combination of the letters: BCEFHIKLNOQR.
>
>  [image]
>
>  B. Since one of the letters is only 1-symbol long in Morse (no second symbol), this would have to be 'E' (.), since 'T' (-) is not among the letterset in Point A.
>
>  C. We know that all 6 of the other letters must have dots as their second Morse symbol. Valid letters would be: BCDFHIKNSUVXY. The crossover with the letterset in Point A yields only BCFHIKN as possibles.
>
>  [image]
>
>  With these deductions in place, it was a short guesswork step to conclude that the first word could be '**CHICKEN**'. A quick check that its pigpen and Morse symbols satisfied the expected counts came back positive - this word was likely correct! (Especially given the 'farm' link in the title...)

Turning my attention to word 2, I made some further deductions:

> D. If the whole phrase was likely to end up describing a sport or game, it was entirely possible that the second word might end in -**ING**. A check of the pigpen and Morse for these letters showed they could well be valid.
>
>  E. Removing the pigpen segments for 'ING' from the expected total left me needing 4 letters that between them totalled 4 Left segments, 3 Top segments, 2 Right segments, 4 Bottom segments and 1 Dot. Notably, all 4 would need to have *both* a Left and Bottom segment. The only letters satisfying this were: BCEFKLNO.
>
>  [image]
>
>  F. Again, this word required one letter to be one symbol long in Morse (no second symbol) - of the list above, this had to be **E**.
>
>  So armed with an 'E' and an 'ING', it was another short guesswork step to come up with the word '**FENCING**' (using F, N and C from the letter set). Another quick check that its pigpen and Morse symbols satisfied the expected counts came back positive - this word was also likely correct! (Especially given the 'sport' link in the title...)

So, all in all, our 'farm-related sport' is:

> **CHICKEN FENCING** - a type of boundary material whose name does indeed sound like two sword-fighting hens!

Comment: You got it! Well done! I must say that you seem to be an excellent "guesser". :) It is, however, actually possible to solve this without guessing, or at least without saying "If this, then what?" to a level deeper than 1. But you got it and as usual explained it excellently! Respect! :)

Comment: @Jens Thanks :) 'Guess' probably isn't quite the right word. Hopefully though the deductions I listed go some way down the solution path you were hoping for! My write-up reflects my own route to the answer - I daresay my route to Word 2 was probably more informed by context than by the coding method...!