# Elementary, my dear Louis

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

Felt it was time for another Density™ [puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90049/the-first-density-puzzle). Warning: May require thinking. Enjoy!

[image]

**Final answer: (3,4,4,4)**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First,

> interpret the given dots as Braille numbers. (There's no number sign at the beginning, as there normally would be.)
>
>  This gives: `9 92 7 74 53 90 6 2 109 47 16`

Next,

> take the chemical symbols of those elements of the periodic table.
>  This gives `F U N W I Th C He Mt Ag S`, or **FUN WITH CHEM TAGS**.

Title explanation:

> "Elementary" of course refers to the chemical elements; "Louis" is Louis Braille, inventor and namesake of his writing system for the blind.

Comment: Very nice! Can you also relate the puzzle to the title?

Comment: Which Louis had a part in the solution?