# Density™ 3 - The Game!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher, steganography

<sub>The last Density™ puzzle (here: [Density™ finally back from holiday!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105568/density-finally-back-from-holiday/)) proved that OP plays too many games, so we went ahead and created a game of our own!</sub>

If you'd like to create your own Density™ puzzle, the rules are as follows:

<sub>1. The resolution of the grid is 72x72 squares</sub>

<sub>2. No words, text, numbers or symbols can be used</sub>

<sub>3. The tags should indicate what types of solving strategies are required</sub>

<sub>4. You must specify the number of words + letters in the final answer</sub>

---

## Density Puzzle #3

Where is our fictional game taking place?

> [image: Density Puzzle #3]
>
> **Final answer: (8, 3, 7)**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is

> Auckland Harbour Bridge

at

> (-36.83, 174.75)

and the (8,3,7) solution is

> AUCKLAND NEW ZEALAND.

You can see

> the bridge and its immediate environs in the circle at top right, and (in a rather different view) in the large image -- though I'm not sure what view would show you the curve in the southern road without also showing the protruding jetty/pier/whatever-it-is that's visible in the inset. Maybe it's a post-apocalyptic game set in a future where that jetty/pier/whatever is underwater? [OP clarifies that this is just a minor inaccuracy in drawing and not significant.]

The 3x3 grids are

> digits, as follows:
>
> ```
> ... 0    #.. 1    #.. 2    ##. 3    ... 4
> ...      ...      #..      #..      ...
> ...      ...      ...      ...      #..
>
> #.. 5    #.. 6    ##. 7    ... 8    #.. 9
> ...      #..      #..      ...      ...
> #..      #..      #..      ##.      ##.
> ```

which we may explain

> by supposing that cells in the first two rows count 1 and cells in the bottom row count 4, but as we'll see that's not exactly the right rule.

The grids at top right

> give northings and eastings; the northings are red because they are *negative*, New Zealand being in the southern hemisphere [citation needed].

Now, what about the 3x3 blocks at top left?

> It seems likely that they say PSE somehow. The third is a 5, strongly suggesting A1Z26, and I think the intended rule is that the scoring goes as follows:
>
> ```
> 114
> 144
> 444
> ```
>
> .

Then

> the blocks indicate the numbers 16, 19, 5, which is exactly what we need to make PSE. (Note: in the original version of the puzzle there was a minor error that made this not quite work, but it's been fixed now.)

The bars at top left

> look like they measure 12, 11, 4 pixels respectively. Again A1Z26 yields nothing useful (LKD) and if there's useful information here I'm failing to see what it is. [OP clarifies in comments that they're just window-dressing.]

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there are 6 cells worth 4 in the grids which are filled starting from the bottom row and going up. This means your initial thought of the letters at top left were right and gives 27 numbers to work with to cover all of the alphabet

Comment: Looking at it again, that wouldn't work for the middle letter, so maybe it's something else after all.

Comment: Nicely done! I've deliberated with the community as to how we tie up the loose ends, so I'll leave a comment below for you and then perhaps you might want to edit your answer?

Comment: rot13(Gur zvavznc + 3q ivrj nera'g va nyvtazrag orpnhfr zl ZF Cnvag fxvyyf fhpx yby. Lbh ner pbeerpg gung gur hfre'f anzr vf "CFR" naq gur pnfg ohggbaf ner 1, 2 naq 3 (pbzzba sbe zbfg ZZBECTf). Gur 3k3 tevqf ner rapbqvat onfr 4 ahzoref, nf lbh nyernql unir rknzcyrf sbe 1, 2, 3, 5, 16, na 19, V'yy yrg lbh svther bhg ubj gur flfgrz jbexf. Gur ETO onef ner whfg urnygu, znan naq fgnzvan (fb qrpbengvir bayl))

Comment: Should also be noted that the answer is the hometown of OP :D

Comment: Well @Dmihawk I've made some edits but I'm still very confused about the exact interpretation of the 3x3 grids. I _have_ found a rule that gives the "right" answers but I can't help suspecting that something simpler is intended.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I goofed! :o sorry about that :(

Comment: Ah! No apology needed -- it can happen to anyone. I'm relieved that I wasn't missing something clever-but-obvious :-).

Comment: I see the puzzle image has had the slip-up fixed; I've amended my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Gareth McCaughan is 100% correct, but I made a mistake on the original post of the question - to clarify the number system, my notes from making the puzzle are below

> [image: Density3NumberSystem]
>
> These represent the numbers from 1 - 26 (left to right, top to bottom)
>
> In the Density:
>
> - Symbols in black are positive numbers
>
> - Symbols in red are negative numbers
>
> - Symbols in white are A1Z26 encoded letters

Answer (score 0):

**PARTIAL ANSWER**

The symbols below the "planet" correspond to coordinates in the real world. I haven't found the pattern to generate all the digits, but given the ones at the bottom (the "inventory" to call it some way), it'd need to have a structure like:

`N3a.b3, E1cd.ce`

Considering possible coordinates, I'd say it is somewhere in Japan, probably inside or near Tokyo (whose approximate coords are 35.690, 139.690)

Comment: This is a _very_ partial answer, with literally no confirmed progress, and would've been better off as a comment. Please don't post partials without some significant progress.

Comment: Can you also explain the structure? I've never seen that kind of notation before (at first reading I thought it was chess)

Comment: I am not convinced that the digits you think are 3s are actually 3s. (I agree that they are numbers and that they are probably coordinates.) My reason for being unconvinced is that I _suspect_ the ones at top left are 16, 19, 5 signifying P,S,E, which to me suggests some sort of additive thing where each of the 3x3 cells has a value, and that three-on-the-left will be worth strictly more than 5.

Comment: Er, actually it's not three-on-the-left that you're saying makes 3, so I'm not sure how much evidence against your 3s that is even if I'm right about PSE. But I'm not sure what evidence _for_ the 3s there is; is there any reason why the numbers at the bottom should be 1,2,3?

Comment: The different colours of the northings and eastings (if that's what they are) at top right suggests to me that one (probably the red one) is _negative_, which would put this in the southern hemisphere.

Comment: ... Actually, I think I know where this is.